# Using SQL create column for date combining year, month and day columns, where few year, month, or date are NULL

Tags: date, missing-data

I have three separate columns of Year, Month, and Day. Unfortunately few Year, Month, or Day are NULL. How do I create a Date column combining those three columns where Year, Month, and Day are not NULL?

I tried,
,datefromparts (Year, Month, Day) where Year is not NULL or Month is not NULL or Day is not NULL  as 'Date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the code. All of the below work. Anyone can be used

```
 -- ,case when Year is not null and Month is not null and Day is not null then datefromparts (Year, Month, Day)
```

when Year is not null and Month is not null and Day is null then datefromparts (Year, Month, 15)  end as 'Date'
--,COALESCE (Year, '') + '-' + COALESCE (Month, '') + '-' + COALESCE (Day, '') as 'Date'
--,datefromparts (Year, Month, Day) as 'Date'
--,datefromparts (ISNULL(Year, null), ISNULL(Month, null), ISNULL(Day, null)) as 'Date'
--,datefromparts (ISNULL(Year, '1900'), ISNULL(Month, '01'), ISNULL(Day, '01')) as 'Date'
--,TRY_CONVERT (Date, datefromparts (Year, Month, Day)) as 'Date'
--,TRY_CONVERT (Date, datefromparts (ISNULL(Year, '1900'), ISNULL(Month, '01'), ISNULL(Day, '01'))) as 'Date'
--,TRY_CONVERT (Date, datefromparts (Year, Month, Day)) as 'Date'
--,Case when Year is not null then datefromparts (Year, Month, Day) end as 'Date'